# Java EE secure redirect between multiple login types

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have implemented both `kerberos` `sso` login and username/password login for my J2EE web app.

`sso.jsp` handles single sign on and `login.jsp` handles username/password login respectively.

User access www.example.com/index.jsp and in `index.jsp` I will check if the configured login type (in the configuration file) is `SSO` or `Database` and redirects the user to the respective jsp pages.

But there is a security issue that the user is able to access www.example.com/login.jsp when I have set the configuration login type to `SSO`.

How do I prevent the user from directing accessing `login.jsp` and yet is able to access `login.jsp`, when I set the login type to `Database`, which stands for username/password authentication, and vice versa for `SSO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you detect the request to `login.jsp`, check if the login type is `sso`, and then redirect to `sso.jsp`? This should be done in a servlet filter.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/login.jsp")
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final String loginType = request.getParameter("login-type");

        final HttpServletResponse servletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if ("sso".equalsIgnoreCase(loginType)) {
            final String redirectUrl = "sso.jsp";
            servletResponse.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

}
```